# How to link a dynamically created image into Facebook share?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am confused how to go about this problem I have. On my site, after a user fills out a form, an image is generated on the canvas element.

This is the image I want the user to be able to share on facebook through a share dialog. Now I know how to convert from canvas to png, but not before the page has loaded.

Using opengraph like this works,

```
<meta property="og:image" content="sample_chart.png" />
```

only if the image is an existing png. And there seems no way to add an image to this property once the user has arrived at the page.

What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user generates the image, store it on your server and generate a unique URL for that image that contains the direct URL to the image in the Open Graph tags of that page.

For example, this is how the markup of that page could look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/path/to/image.png" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/awesome/image.html" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="A title" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="A description" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://example.com/path/to/image.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note the part about the unique URL is very important. It doesn't need to be the URL for the page the user is on.